# p value in case of comparing several features

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I have 2 populations A and B.
I would like to test whether the difference in 100 features are significant between population A and population B.
For each feature I compute the p value. Should I correct the p value since I am testing different features?

Comment: You can think of some kind of multiple comparisons correction unless you looking for mental activity in dead salmons fMRI scans (http://prefrontal.org/files/posters/Bennett-Salmon-2009.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It's advisable to control either the Family-wise error rate (FWER) or the False discovery rate (FDR).

- **FWER**: estimate of the occurrence of at least one type-I error (lesser false positive rate, higher false negative rate)
- **FDR**: estimate of the rate of type-I errors (higher false positive rate, lesser false negative rate)

The reason is simple, the more tests you do the more likely is to reject a null by chance. Check [the article at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem#Definition).